# winstonjs Get logger created with winston.createLogger(...)

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, winston

***Question***
Winston provides `winston.loggers.get("logger name")` in order to get a logger. How do I get a logger created using `winston.createLogger(options)` ***(it does not have a name)***

***Why I'm asking***
I've created a logger in a file using `winston.createLogger(options)`, and then export the created logger using `module.exports`.

I'd like to use this logger throughout my application but everytime I `require("")` it, `createLogger(options)` is called, thus creating a new logger every time.

***Code sample***

```
const winston = require('winston');

// this logger does not have a name!
// Thus, how do I get it.
const logger = winston.createLogger({});


module.exports = logger;
```

Comment: Yeah that's the only way if you want to work on it on multiples files via require, it's simple as a stream.
(I suppose you don't work with cluster mod or fork, because if it is you can pass arguments in some cases, that suppose the other file is executed as a child_process)

Comment: How are you using your logger module?  I don't see any problem with what you're doing that would cause multiple loggers to get created.  Node caches the module.exports from the first require() and returns it to subsequent calls.

Comment: My concern is that multiple files will contain **require('logger.js')**, resulting in the logger being created multiple times. I did not know node cached **require()** so I suppose my concerns are invalid. Thank you **Jim Baldwin**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Formal answer for posterity:

Multiple require() calls in a single node.js process will not create new instances of the module.  The first one will, then subsequent calls will return a reference to the first one.  This is by design, and very handy.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who still want's to be able to get a winston logger by name when it was created using `createLogger()`, I haven't found an answer.

But, you can do it this way.
**Create the logger using** `winston.loggers.add(name, options)`
**Get the logger using** `winston.loggers.get(name)`

Also, Node JS `require()` caches modules. WHO KNEW!

Thanks for the help.